# Using RxJS correctly with fetch request

Tags: react-native, rxjs

I am trying to fetch request a POST to my Server. I want to use it with RxJS to better overview my Response Data. Now i may have problems using it correctly...

**I call the RxJS fetch in my Component after a Button click where i give it some parameters:**

```
_btnSendCode: function () {
    var self = this;
    var RelationShipModel = require('../NetworkUtils/RelationShipModel');
    var relationShipType = RelationShipModel(currentIndex);
    var InvitationAction = require('../../../Flux/Actions/InvitationAction');
    InvitationAction.createInvitation(this.state.familyID, relationShipType, this.state.adminSwitch, AuthStore.getUserTokenWithBearer());
    //self.props.navigator.pop();
}
```

**Here is my createInvitation:**

```
var Rx = require('rx');

function notifyMessage(msg:string) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        ToastAndroid.show(msg, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    } else {
        AlertIOS.alert(msg);
    }
}

createInvitation: function (familyID, type, isAdmin, userToken) {
    let source = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        fetch(API_URL + 'families/' + familyID + '/invitations', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Authorization': userToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'type': type,
                'isAdmin': isAdmin
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(j => {
                observer.onNext(j);
                observer.onCompleted();
            }).catch(observer.onError);
    }).flatMap(function (array) {
        return Rx.Observable.from(array);
    });

    let subscription = source.subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('onNext: %s', x);
            //Dispatcher.dispatch({
            //    actionType: ActionTypes.CREATE_INVITATION,
            //    data: JSON.parse(response._bodyText)
            //});
        },
        function (e) {
            console.log('onError: %s', e);
            notifyMessage(e.message);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('onCompleted');
        }
    );

    console.log(subscription);
```

So the problem is, that onNext,onError or onCompleted is never excecuted. What could be the problem? My fetch reponse should be correct. But even if it isn´t correct, shouldn´t i get the error message in my onError?

Comment: Have you tried to debug to see what part of the code is being executed and which part not?? You deal with promises, if a promise does not resolve, you are left hanging, so log trace your code. For Rxjs, you can use the `tap` operator to trace what is passed in the observables. Let us know what you found.

Comment: Your fetch code might be incorrect, because you are not calling `catch(observer.onerror)` on the first promise.

Comment: Where do you mean i missed catch()? In my code i always include it...

Answer (score 1):

Your code might break without firing `observer.onError` if `JSON.stringify` fires an exception, say if trying to serialise an object with circular data structures.

Not saying that's the actual issue, let's try to break your problem into smaller testable chunks, so at least we'll know which part is keeps failing and why.

Also, I'd suggest splitting your code into smaller observables, to make error handling a tad easier:

```
const body$ = Observable.create( obs => {
    try {
        const body = JSON.stringify({type: ..., isAdmin: ...})
        obs.onNext(body)
        obs.onCompleted()
    } catch (err) {
        obs.onError(err)
    }

})
const request$ = body$.flatMap(
                        body => Observable.of( fetch(..., {body, ...}))
                    )
                    .do(...) // start with this if still having issues
                    .catch(...) // you should be able to drop this one later

const source$ = request$.flatMap(
   res => Observable.of(res.json())
).catch(...)

source$.subscribe(...)
```

Can't run this code atm, but hope the general gist is clear - usually it pays off to have smaller, testable observables.